# How to send keys to the element in focus with WebExecute

Tags: web-access, webtools, webdriver

Exploring the `WebExecute` function, I would like to know how can I send key (or TypeElement) to the element in focus. Here is a toy code using Google.

```
StartWebSession["Chrome"]
WebExecute["OpenPage" -> "www.google.com"]
WebExecute["ClickElement" -> "XPath" -> "//input[@name = 'q']"];
```

Now that the text area is selected, I tried to implement [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307910) Javascript solution (with no success) using:

```
WebExecute["JavascriptExecute"->"browser.actions().sendKeys('Test').perform();"]
```

Any clue on how to do this in Mathematica?

[image]

**Note**: I know that for this toy code I can type in the text area using:

```
WebExecute["TypeElement" -> {First@WebExecute["LocateElements" -> "XPath" -> "//input[@name = 'q']"], "Test"}]
```

But my real case is more complex than this, and type in the focus area should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some web search, I found this solution using this interesting CSS Pseudo-class `focus`.

```
StartWebSession["Chrome"]
WebExecute["OpenPage" -> "www.google.com"]
input = First@WebExecute["LocateElements" -> "CSSSelector" -> "input:focus"]
WebExecute["TypeElement" -> {input,"Test"}];
```

Here is the reference [post](https://saucelabs.com/blog/selenium-tips-finding-elements-by-their-focus-using-focus-a-css-pseudo-class).